# Adding a NSTextView subview to NSTabViewItem

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, resize, nsview

OK, I admit I've never been that good with programmatically manipulating `NSView` and its resizing. So, here I am :

- We've got a **Tab View**
- We're adding a new `NSTabViewItem`
- Each `NSTabViewItem` will contain one `NSTextView` in it, which stretches and occupies all space of the `NSTabViewItem`.

**Here's my code :**

```
NSTabViewItem *newItem = [[(NSTabViewItem*)[NSTabViewItem alloc] initWithIdentifier:newDocument] autorelease];

NSTextView* tv = [[NSTextView alloc] initWithFrame:NSZeroRect];
[tv makeStretchable];

[[newItem view] setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
[[newItem view] addSubview:tv];
[newItem setLabel:@"Untitled"];
[tabView addTabViewItem:newItem]; 
[tabView selectTabViewItem:newItem];
```

**My `NSView` category (for `makeStretchable`) :**

```
#define FIX_LEFT    NSViewMinXMargin
#define FIX_RIGHT   NSViewMaxXMargin
#define FIX_TOP     NSViewMinYMargin
#define FIX_BOTTOM  NSViewMaxYMargin
#define FIX_WIDTH   NSViewWidthSizable
#define FIX_HEIGHT  NSViewHeightSizable

- (void)makeStretchable
{
    [self setAutoresizingMask:FIX_LEFT|FIX_TOP|FIX_BOTTOM|
                              FIX_RIGHT|FIX_WIDTH|FIX_HEIGHT];
}
```

**The issue :**

- The `NSTextView` is minimal (like one line only) and sitting in the very center of each `NSTabViewItem`

---

I'm sure it has something to do with my resizing mask (or perhaps the way I'm adding the view?), but I still cannot figure it out. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your FIX_* should be FLEX_*, including FIX_LEFT, FIX_RIGHT etc.

Now change your makeStretchable into:

```
[self setAutoresizingMask:FLEX_WIDTH|FLEX_HEIGHT];
```

That should do it. :)

A bit of history:
In the old Interface Builder (up to and including 2.x), springs represented the 'set' bits.
In the new Interface Builder (from 3 and up), the springs were replaced by 'fixtures', which makes a lot more sense, but it also means that you need to do some oposite thinking, when you're changing the flags programmatically.

Thus the meaning of the flags (from Apple's docs) are:

NSViewMinXMargin: "The left margin between the receiver and its superview is flexible."
NSViewWidthSizable: "The receiver’s width is flexible."
NSViewMaxXMargin: "The right margin between the receiver and its superview is flexible."
...and so on; eg. all set bits are 'flexible', otherwise they're 'fixed'...

Comment: The funny thing is that I made it work by exactly the opposite way : by removing everything **but** : `FIX_WIDTH` and `FIX_HEIGHT`

Comment: I may have misunderstood the meaning of FIX_*; I find the NS* names less confusing (will Apple ever remove the confusion from Cocoa?). -But according to your #define, the FIX_WIDTH and FIX_HEIGHT are 'inverted'. Note: if your view has no flags set, it'll center horizontally and vertically, but it won't stretch.

Comment: Well, it's because of that... Cocoa confusion, that I've tried "taming" auto-resizing masks using Macros and Definitions. Though in that particular case, it turned out to be the wrong choice... (more than often, it's *not*) lol

Comment: Just rename FIX_WIDTH to FLEX_WIDTH, then you're good to go. :) -Which means I'll have to edit my answer...

Comment: I'll definitely consider it! :-)

Comment: My answer is now corrected. I hope that you won't find the coordinate system and 'setFlipped' / 'isFlipped' as confusing as I do.